# MySQL 5.7.21 Installed Mac but have Preferences Error

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed the new MySQL 5.7.21(macOS 10.13 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive) on an iMac (Retina 5k, macOS version 10.13.2). However, I could not run the MySQL from the System Preferences.

The message shows:

```
Preferences Error. Could not load MySQL preference pane.
```

I installed to my laptop computer (MacBook Pro), but the same Preferences Error popped up.

Is there anyone who can help me out for this type of problem?

Answer (score 6):

"The solution for me was to remove MySQL Preference Pane (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-remove-preference-panes-from-mac-2260890) and install it again from the 5.7.20 DMG Archive (you can still find it on various FTP)."

This solution totally worked for me. Thank you! Is there a way to report this bug? If the preferences pane is broken in 5.7.21 ... seems like a lot of us will experience this problem.

Found 5.7.20 here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of digging around online. It looks like others have has this issue with previous versions of MySQL too. I did find this thread relevant to the current version I believe. https://devmarketer.io/learn/do-not-install-mysql-macos-sierra-how-to-fix/ , I haven't had a chance to follow through with it yet but I will get back with the results when I do.

Answer (score 0):

The Preference Pane is broken in this version of MySQL. Simply copying over the one from 5.7.20 does not work, as other components are involved too (probably launch agents or daemons), so installation is needed. The preference pane's filesize is much smaller than in previous versions of MySQL. Oracle need to fix this.

I have reported it as a bug to Oracle:
http://bugs.mysql.com/89357

Answer (score 0):

try to install x86, 64-bit version instead of ARM